# Calcular la media anual en el siguiente caso en python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Dispongo del siguiente DataFrame:

```py
fechas = [2018, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2017, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019]
conductor = [8, 1009, 1043, 3015, 5003, 2063, 1009, 2059, 2057, 1003, 2039, 5003, 1003, 3025, 2055, 3028, 3028, 4001, 2055, 3025, 8001, 1033, 2025, 4001, 5004, 2021, 2039, 8005, 8001, 3025]
ids = ['5HV14A7N4191065', '56A0J94EU650259', '5N80GZEQB871540', '56U0JYVTU034324', '5NH0ZXP4G368593', '5F211S22X011628', '56A14E0BH824401', '5A10IXBDO046285', '58T0HM4GC419554', '50F0H36D0410259', '4UN0IN80M012793', '5AU13NNYG339672', '5150YA78X454382', '5MC14QXH1854905', '57M0HAOI5630285', '5LA118FVY083801', '5LQ12OXJ0248492', '5O416NZAF039647', '54G0LZAW8686078', '5FH0L5C7D020670', '5550KUT20335062', '4XD0PFLYW466153', '5OH13KDZ9137589', '5GB12YKYS160425', '58S0HILWG243127', '5350JH5AE219104', '5450IO02I052728', '5GA0HGSHQ105702', '5GF0II2B4962164', '5JF0JK2XN358906']
almacen = [5, 1, 1, 101, 103, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 103, 1, 101, 3, 101, 101, 102, 3, 101, 6, 1, 3, 102, 103, 3, 3, 6, 6, 101]
litros = [760, 400, 399, 125, 500, 1000, 1000, 3000, 1001, 214, 1229, 400, 1000, 290, 235, 1720, 796, 2000, 755, 550, 4000, 865, 848, 4545, 700, 787, 500, 400, 400, 7000]

data = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids,'conductor':conductor,'almacen':almacen, 'litros':litros,'fecha':fechas})
```

y quiero calcular a partir de él una tabla que muestre la media de pedidos anuales por conductor en cada centro, no quiero saber el valor de cada conductor sino en promedio de conductores. Por ejemplo si en el año 2017 en el centro 1 hubo un total de 20 pedidos (lo saco contando los ID), y tiene ese centro 3 conductores, el pedido promedio seria 20/3 = 6,67, ese sería el valor que debería aparecer en la celda correspondiente a 2017, centro 1. Adjunto la imagen de una tabla modelo para hacerse una idea.
[image: tabla de pedidos medios por conductor y año]

La fila de los promedios me da bastante igual no es necesaria.

El código que yo tengo ahora mismo es este:

```py
data.groupby([data.conductor,data.almacen,data.fecha])['conductor'].size().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Pero no es ni siquiera aproximado al objetivo.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo siguiendo éstos pasos:

- Agrupa por almacén y fecha y aplica `count`, ésto te dará los pedidos por almacén y año.
- Agrupa por almacén y aplica `pandas.Series.nonunique()` para obtener el número de conductores de cada almacén.
- Divide las dos series, desapila y rellena los `NaN` con ceros.

---

```
import pandas as pd


fechas = [2018, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2017,
          2017, 2018, 2017, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2019,
          2018, 2017, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019]

conductor = [8, 1009, 1009, 3015, 5003, 2063, 1009, 2059, 2057, 1009,
             2039, 5003, 1009, 3025, 2055, 3028, 3028, 4001, 2055, 3025,
             8001, 1033, 2025, 4001, 5004, 2021, 2039, 8005, 8001, 3025]

ids = ['5HV14A7N4191065', '56A0J94EU650259', '5N80GZEQB871540', '56U0JYVTU034324',
       '5NH0ZXP4G368593', '5F211S22X011628', '56A14E0BH824401', '5A10IXBDO046285',
       '58T0HM4GC419554', '50F0H36D0410259', '4UN0IN80M012793', '5AU13NNYG339672',
       '5150YA78X454382', '5MC14QXH1854905', '57M0HAOI5630285', '5LA118FVY083801',
       '5LQ12OXJ0248492', '5O416NZAF039647', '54G0LZAW8686078', '5FH0L5C7D020670',
       '5550KUT20335062', '4XD0PFLYW466153', '5OH13KDZ9137589', '5GB12YKYS160425',
       '58S0HILWG243127', '5350JH5AE219104', '5450IO02I052728', '5GA0HGSHQ105702',
       '5GF0II2B4962164', '5JF0JK2XN358906']

almacen = [5, 1, 1, 101, 103, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 103, 1, 101, 3, 101,
           101, 102, 3, 101, 6, 1, 3, 102, 103, 3, 3, 6, 6, 101]

litros = [760, 400, 399, 125, 500, 1000, 1000, 3000, 1001, 214,
          1229, 400, 1000, 290, 235, 1720, 796, 2000, 755, 550,
          4000, 865, 848, 4545, 700, 787, 500, 400, 400, 7000]

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'id': ids, 'conductor': conductor, 'almacen': almacen,
     'litros': litros, 'fecha': fechas}
     )
```

---

```
res = (data.groupby(["almacen", "fecha"])["id"].count() /
       data.groupby(["almacen"])['conductor'].nunique()
       ).unstack().fillna(0)

res.loc["Promedio"] = res.mean(axis=0)
```

> ```
> >>> res      
>
>    fecha      2017        2018        2019        2020
>  almacen              
>        1  1.500000    1.000000    0.500000    0.000000
>        3  0.285714    0.714286    0.142857    0.142857
>        5  0.000000    1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
>        6  0.000000    0.500000    1.000000    0.000000
>      101  0.000000    0.333333    1.666667    0.000000
>      102  0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    1.000000
>      103  0.000000    1.000000    0.500000    0.000000  
> Promedio  0.255102    0.649660    0.687075    0.163265
> ```

Comment: Había pensado hacerlo en dos fases, pero no me dejaba aplicar drop_duplicates() al resultado del groupby. Muchas gracias de nuevo. Sin intención de molestar, he visto que me has respondido a varias preguntas sobre el tema. Estoy bastante interesado en el tratamiento de datos, pero no he encontrado tutoriales ni información en condiciones para aprender sobre el tema. Lo que he visto se queda muy corto. Donde me recomendarías buscar esta información o que material concreto usarías. Gracias.